# SwiftSyntax - Why objects are not compatible?

Tags: swift

I'm playing with SwiftSyntax library. However, by some reason, I cannot get it work.

I created a sample test case with code

```swift
let type = Mirror(reflecting: stmt).subjectType
let staticType = FunctionDeclSyntax.self
let comp = stmt is FunctionDeclSyntax
let testObj = stmt as? FunctionDeclSyntax
if type == staticType {
    print(comp)
    print(testObj)
}
```

I ran a debug (the breakpoint is on the `if`)
[image]

Why? How to check if `stmt` is `FunctionDeclSyntax`?